# makefile for multiple files not working

Tags: c++, linux, makefile

I have multiple cpp files .i have a make file a makefile for compilation, but when i make all it gives me nothing to do

```
CC=g++
PWD=`pwd`
ARCH=$(shell uname -s)
CFLAGS=-Wall -g -fPIC

LIBSOURCES=./libsrc/Backup/BackupLib.cpp \
./libsrc/Backup/BackupBase.cpp \
./libsrc/Backup/TransferManager.cpp

LIBOBJECTS:=$(LIBSOURCES:.cpp=.o) 

INCLUDE= -I /usr/include/libxml2/ -I ./System/ -I ./SubSystem/Queue/ -I ./System/Threads/ -I ./ -I 

./SubSystem/DB/ -I ./Controller/ -I ./SubSystem/Watcher/

MYDEFINE=-D__LINUX__ -D__cplusplus -D__CLEARCACHE__ 

LIBFLAG=-shared -Wl

LDFLAGS=-ldl -lpthread -lsqlite3 -lcrypto -lssl -lxml2 -L ./lib/ -lBackupLib 

LDLIBFLAGS=-ldl -lpthread -lsqlite3 -lcrypto -lssl -lxml2  

all:    $(LIBSOURCES) $(LIBCOMPBKUP)    

$(LIBCOMPBKUP): $(LIBOBJECTS)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(LIBOBJECTS) $(INCLUDE) $(MYDEFINE) -I ./libsrc/Backup/ -o $@

.cpp.o:
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(INCLUDE) $(MYDEFINE) -I ./libsrc/Backup/ ./$< -c -o ./$@
```

The output of make all cmd is **make: Nothing to be done for `all'**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see no definition of `LIBCOMPBKUP`.

So, the `all` target expands to:

```
all:  ./libsrc/Backup/BackupLib.cpp ./libsrc/Backup/BackupBase.cpp ./libsrc/Backup/TransferManager.cpp
```

and `make` rightly concludes there's nothing to do.

Your `all` target should just depend solely on `$(LIBCOMPBKUP)` (once you correctly define it), and things should start working from there.

You need a line like:

```
LIBCOMPBKUP = BackupLib.so
```

or similar so that your rule to build `$(LIBCOMPBKUP)` has some meaning.

Comment: but it is defined below all??

Comment: @singh :  No, it isn't.  The left side of that rule expands to an empty string because the variable `LIBCOMPBKUP` isn't defined.  If that variable was defined and expanded to something, then `make` would have a useful rule there.

Comment: BTW, I don't remember if `make` recognizes `.so` as a suffix by default. (I think it does.)  If it doesn't, then add a line near the top that says `.SUFFIXES: .so` to teach it that `.so` is a meaningful suffix.